# Install JSL or JSlint with Node/Npm  on Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, jslint, npm

How do I install jsl-0.3.0 on ubuntu 11.10?

I have downloaded the tarball from [JSL](http://www.javascriptlint.com/download.htm). However there isn't a configure script or autogen.sh to enable to build it from source.

Tried using npm to install it but it was unsuccessful as it could extract the tarball.

```
sayth@sayth-TravelMate-5740G:~/jsl-0.3.0/src$ sudo npm install ~/Downloads/jsl-0.3.0-   src.tar.gz -g
npm ERR! couldn't unpack /tmp/npm-1324904212208/1324904212208-0.02443970972672105/tmp.tgz to /tmp/npm-1324904212208/1324904212208-0.02443970972672105/contents
```

I previously tried installing jslint via npm but that failed also.

```
sayth@sayth-TravelMate-5740G:~/jsl-0.3.0/src$ sudo npm install jslint -g
npm ERR! error installing jslint@0.1.2 Error: Refusing to delete: /usr/local/bin/jslint not in /usr/local/lib/node_modules/jslint
```

I installed node and npm via the script at http://apptob.org/. This installed node 0.6.5 and I have now updated it to 0.6.6 in an attempt to correct these errors.

Could anyone provide a suggestion on how I could get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried install nodeJS from the website, that will also install npm. Once both are installed, you may simply run `npm install jslint` .